# Strategies for persisting and using original business object state

Tags: c#, .net, oop

There are many scenarios where you would want to save the original state of the object when the object is first instantiated in order to be able to compare its current state to its original state and establish if the object was modified during its lifetime either by a user or programmatically and to track if the object is modified and/or persistable, compare current and original values etc.

How do you go about doing this plumbing? Are you using some code generators available that would do this plumbing for you? Are you aware of any formalized best practices? 
ReSharper will generate object comparison code for you but I did not find anything that would generate the rest of the plumbing...

Here is what I'm currently doing (short, simpilfied version):

```
public class MyObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        private set { id = value; OnPropertyChanged("Id"); }
    }
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { 
                if (value == name) return;
                name = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
                CheckIfModified();
            }
    }

    public bool IsModified { get; private set; }
    public bool IsPersistable { get; private set; }
    public MyObject OriginalState { get; private set; }

    public MyObject(int id, string name, bool saveOriginalState = false)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;

        if (saveOriginalState) OriginalState = new MyObject(id, name);
    }
    ///... More BI code (determine if modified/persistable etc...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way (high level):

1. Serialize the original object.  Use binary, XML, or JSON serialization.  (XML and JSON will be easier for step #3)
2. Serialize the potentially-modified instance using the same method as the prior step.
3. Compare the two serialized versions.  If they're the same, the object hasn't been changed.

Comment: @jeyoung that's far more code to write, because you'd have to incorporate all properties into the hash.  and it's not future-proof, because ever time you add a property, you have to change the gethashcode method again.

Comment: ReSharper already does that for you by implementing IEqualityComparer<T>, but it's not just about comparing the two objects, there is a lot more Business Intelligence to implement if you want a smart object. Applying business rules to establish if the object is persistable for example, comparing current to original values, change notification etc...

Comment: @codenoire You are right about having to write more code for an implementation of `GetHashCode`, but I prefer that as a cleaner approach. If quick-n-easy, by all means, serialize and compare.